# Find solution of an equation w.r.t. a measure

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given $g: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ a bounded function, $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\mathbb R$. I'm looking for a function $f$ such that
$$g(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}\Big( \frac{f(x+y)-f(y)}{y}\chi_{(y\neq 0)}+ f'(x)\chi_{(y=0)}\Big)\mu(dy)$$
for all a.e. $x\in \mathbb R$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of set $A\subset \mathbb R$. Whether such a function $f$ does exist? If $\mu =\delta_{0}$ is the Dirac measure, then $g(x)=f'(x)$ and we have $f(x)=a+ \int_0^x g(u)du$. However I don't know the solution for general $\mu$. Does anyone have idea?

Comment: If $\mu(\{0\}) = 0$, which is the case for example when $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then the second term in the integrand will integrate to $0$.

Comment: Some decomposition of $\mu$ might be helpful, e.g. $\mu = \mu(\{0\}) \delta + \nu$ where $\nu(\{0\}) = 0$ or perhaps using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem

Comment: @md2perpe Thank you! Your idea is helpful. Do you know any equation forms $g(x)=\int_{\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}} \frac{f(x+y)-f(y)}{y}\mu (dy)$, where given $g$?